Python - how to Re-index a column starting from 1 to n numbers in a CSV file
I have tried to Re-index a CSV file with three columns of which the first column is a string (not integer).
I would like the first row in the first column starts from 1, 2, 3, ..., n, etc. where n is the total number of rows (without headers' row) in the above CSV file.
    Here is the original CSV file:

    count,username,user_id
    1200,ZMQ1314,5406865623
    1201,Bongtuy,1076568810
    1202,Tingcall,1469929831
    1203,rithboren47,1503590446
    1204,Bongheue,1464987984
    ... etc.


    I would like to Re-write a new CSV file without changing any data in second and third column like this:

    count,username,user_id
    1,ZMQ1314,5406865623
    2,Bongtuy,1076568810
    3,Tingcall,1469929831
    4,rithboren47,1503590446
    5,Bongheue,1464987984
    ... etc.



    I have tried the following codes without success:

    import csv

    with open('data-left.csv', 'r') as f1:
        fileone = f1.readlines()

    with open('data-left2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:    # target_userid2.txt or target_userid2.json
        nf.write('count,username,user_id' + '\n')
        count1 = 1
        for item in fileone:
            if item[1] != "None":
                re_indexing = str(count1)
                record = re_indexing + ',' + item[1] + ',' + item[2]
                nf.write(record)
                count1 += 1

Thanks

You could parse each row using csv.reader which will transform each row into a list of strings, where each string correspond to a cell in your CSV file.
Here's code example:
import csv

with open('data-left.csv', 'r') as f1:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    header = next(reader)  # Skip the header row

    with open('data_left2.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        writer = csv.writer(nf)
        writer.writerow(header)  # Write the header row to the new csv file

        for index, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):  # Start numbering rows from 1
            writer.writerow([index, row[1], row[2]])


Great works correctly, but it has new blank line after each row. How can I remove that blank line? Thanks

I updated with newline='' to remove blank lines after each row

I would highly recommend using the pandas package to work with spreadsheets. First, install the package using
pip install pandas

Once you installed, pandas, here is how you can use it to replace values in your first column.
df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)
# Create a dictionary from original value to new value.
mapping = {1200: 1, 1201: 2, 1202: 3, 1203: 4, 1204: 5}
df["count"] = df["count"].replace(mapping)
df.to_csv("updated_data.csv", index=False)

To make a mapping with an arbitrary number of elements, you can use the following dictionary comprehension:
{i + 1199: i for i in range(1, 6)}

which produces
{1200: 1, 1201: 2, 1202: 3, 1203: 4, 1204: 5}


I could not get file_path correctly. It is like this: C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\dev stuffs\Tools\data cleaners. An error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax; CSV file is in the same as python script. Thanks

Get it working with this df = pd.read_csv("data_left.csv"). How can I create mapping for unlimited index; not just 5? Very appreciate your help.

@JamesBlack - great, please see my edited post. you can use a dictionary comprehension to create the mapping

Thanks for great help. I would like to RE-index starting from 1 to n as each file has different number of row. I think I did not specify this in my post which may cause confusions. Here is what I have tried to achieve: mapping = {df["count"][0:]:{1:}} - starting from first row with index: 1 onwards. Can you please help correct that line? Cheers
